# Convex Polyhedra with Largest Constant Dihedral Angle for Given Number of Faces

Tags: polyhedra

Which $20$ faced convex polyhedron has the largest constant dihedral angle?

Which $24$ faced convex polyhedron has the largest constant dihedral angle?

Also, what about $30$ or $32$ faced polyhedra? How does one go about finding them?

(Note: this is a repost of [a question on Math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320224/convex-polyhedra-with-largest-constant-dihedral-angle-for-given-number-of-faces))

Comment: You should wait more than a few hours after posting on math.stackexchange before posting here. What do you mean by "constant dihedral angle?" All dihedral angles are constant, and they can be arbitrarily close to $\pi$. Do you mean you want to maximize the minimal dihedral angle? 

Comment: @Douglas: I would guess the question means: among those convex icosahedra whose dihedral angles are all equal, which one maximises this dihedral angle?